# ReSeed database in Azure

Tags: c#, azure

I have this inicializer in my project:

```
public class MyInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<AppDbContext>
```

I have also deployed an application in Azure with SQL database.

I would like to clear the whole DB and reseed it with my initializer. How can I do it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the only possible option is to manually delete my DB, then create new DB with same name (so the same connection string) and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your [custom initializer](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19999/Understanding-Database-Initializers-in-Entity-Framework-Code-First.htm)

```
public class MyCustomInitializer : IDatabaseInitializer<AppDbContext>
{
    public void InitializeDatabase(AppDbContext context)
    {
        if (context.Database.Exists())
        {
            context.Database.Delete();
        }
        context.Database.Create();
        // populate data
    }
}
```

Comment: But I don't want to reseed DB all the time, just sometimes when I need it

Comment: And how? I am clearly lost in Azure portal and couldn't google it either

Comment: "To delete a SQL database, click Delete on the SQL database blade." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-portal.

Comment: But then my app does not work because it is not binded to some DB